# How do I find the average of a dataframe column when comparing to another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can't figure out how to phrase the question well, but basically, let's say I have a dataframe with a column of companies, and another column with the prices they charge for a product. For example:

| Company | Price |
| --- | --- |
| A | 50 |
| B | 75 |
| A | 80 |
| C | 10 |

And I want to find the average like the following:

| Company | Price |
| --- | --- |
| A | 65 |
| B | 75 |
| C | 10 |

Is there an efficient way to calculate this? I'm sure there is, I just cant think of it.

Comment: Check the official pandas documentation before asking question here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html

Comment: Try: `df.groupby('Company').mean().reset_index()`

Comment: Yea perfect. I didn't see the groupby and mean. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
df = df.groupby('Company', as_index=False).mean()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Company  Price
0       A   65.0
1       B   75.0
2       C   10.0
```